# how can we measure the voltage upto 2000V

Tags: voltage-measurement

i m having the voltage measurement device of 1000 V. but i have to measure voltage of 2000 V. what are the techniques that can be used to measure this voltage?

Comment: No evidence of any research - question should be closed.

Comment: Did you consider a resistor voltage divider? It might not be the one or even a solution, but at least worth considering. If the concept of a resistor(s) voltage divider is not within your knowledge of electronics, I'd advice you to stay away from  such voltages for Darwinistic reasons.

Comment: Any person who has to ask *here*, sould **not** touch or go anywhere near lethal voltages!

Answer (score 3):

You need a high-voltage probe, readily available on Amazon or your local electronics dealer in the low-hundreds of dollars. They will typically attach to any multimeter.

Note that most of the probes are for high *voltage*, not high *energy* systems. Things like CRT displays, ionizers and some photocopier innards. A general guideline is if it plugs into the wall in the usual way but also produces high voltage, it's in this class.

If you want to check out a 2000V lead from the utility company you need different equipment with better isolation. Expect an extra zero in the price tag.

Why the difference? Touching the 20,000V flyback lead in a CRT display is going to hurt and might damage the equipment, but that's about it. Leakage current from a 2000V 60Hz AC line from the power company is going to be instantly lethal.